# How do I Enable JSON support on nginx

Tags: debian, nginx, raspbian, php5, json

On a raspberry pi I am trying to install ldap-account-manager, which is a php application.

I can successfully browse a simple php script but when browsing to LAM I receive an error indicating `Your PHP has no JSON support! Please install the JSON extension for PHP.`

I have installed php5-json but to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the effort and installed Apache2 instead.  This is a pity, but `nginx` seemed not to be able to provide `json` `php`.

The `nginx` documentation states that `php-json` is compiled into the project so I suspect there is some incompatibility between `ldap-account-manager` and the `json` support in `nginx`.